# Round Average Linq function C#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to round the result of a Average Linq function, is it possible?

```
public IEnumerable<GetLocationsAverageDTO> GetLocationsAverageByCompanyId(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var baseQuery = _dbContext.Answers.AsNoTracking()
                                .Where(p => p.Location.Company.Id == id
                                            && p.Question.Type != QuestionType.Text)
                                .GroupBy(g => new { Location = g.Location.Name })
                                .Select(x =>
                                            new GetLocationsAverageDTO
                                            {
                                                LocationName = x.Key.Location,
                                                Average = x.Average(f => f.Numeric)
                                            })
                                .OrderBy(x => x.LocationName);

        var dto = baseQuery.ToList();

        return dto;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        _logger.Error("[Error in SurveyService.GetLocationsAverageByCompanyId - id: " + id + " - Error: " + error + "]");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Something like

```
Average = x.Average(f => f.Numeric, 2) // result: 45,21
```

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with Linq, more to do with rounding a number to a desired precision no matter where it comes from.

Comment: Can't you use `Math.Round(x.Average(f=> f.Numeric), 2);` ?

Comment: Any request to 'round' a double/decimal in memory, as opposed to when formatting it to text, is usually misguided. Are you sure you need it at this exact point?

Comment: @Habib - probably not (worth a try though) because this is on an IQueryable.

Comment: @Habib Yes, it's working! I was expecting an error from executing a function inside Linq, but no. How this is not generating any error? Can you post your solution because you were the first to respond.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is it not faster to do it there?

Comment: Faster is irrelevant. It (usually) makes no sense to do rounding in a BRL or DAL, that is mixing up responsibilities.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply apply the [Math.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx) function that accepts a second parameter indicating the number of fractional digits you want to the end of your Linq query.

```
Average = Math.Round(x.Average(f => f.Numeric), 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know if the Rounding is translated in SQL-Providers, but you can do an in-Memory iteration and use `Math.Round()` which works in all cases:

```
var dto = baseQuery.ToList();
foreach(var item in dto)
{
    item.Average = Math.Round(item.Average , 2);
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to invoke .ToList() here.

Comment: @EricJ. but we need to store the items in some List as a result. Else, items are lost at the end of the loop.

Comment: @user3185569 They're lost anyway unless the result of `ToList` is stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `x.Average` in [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
.Select(x =>
new GetLocationsAverageDTO 
{
   LocationName = x.Key.Location,
   Average = Math.Round(x.Average(f => f.Numeric), 2)
})
```